# What's the arrow-function doing in this code?

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions, ipfs

The code is from the IPFS (Inter-planetary file-system) HTTP API JS implementation: https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api/blob/master/src/api/add.js

```
'use strict'

const Wreck = require('wreck')

module.exports = (send) => {
    return function add(files, opts, cb) {
        if (typeof(opts) === 'function' && cb === undefined) {
            cb = opts
            opts = {}
        }
        if (typeof files === 'string' && files.startsWith('http')) {
            return Wreck.request('GET', files, null, (err, res) => {
                if (err) return cb(err)

                send('add', null, opts, res, cb)
            })
        }

        return send('add', null, opts, files, cb)
    }
}
```

The function being described is the `add()` function, used to push data to IPFS.

I'll start by explaining what I *do* understand: the `add()` function takes three arguments – if there is no `options` object (the user omitted it) and it's been replaced by a function: the user is trying to implement a callback function instead – change the callback to `opts`; `cb = opts`.

Secondly, if the cited file is a text file `&&` starts with `http` – it's obviously hosted remotely and we need to fetch it using `Wreck`.

All of this I understand, but why are we using the `(send) =>` arrow function? Why do we use `return function add...`? What's the `send('add', null, opts, res, cb)` and `return send('add', null, opts, res, cb)` used for? How is the callback (`cb`) implemented? Help me understand what's happening here

Comment: This is just a factory function, producing other functions and calling them internally. It's not longer necessary with modules, but some people still cling to the pattern.

Comment: @ssube: It's being used to do dependency injection (`send` being the dependency being injected). How would modules make it unnecessary? (Genuine question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole thing being exported is a *function*, which expects `send` as an argument; this lets the calling code do dependency injection by passing in the `send` function to use. It's expecting to be used something like this:

```
let addBuilder = require("add");
let add = addBuilder(senderFunction);
// This function ----^
// is `send` in the `add.js` file.
// It does the actual work of sending the command

// Then being used:
add(someFiles, someOptions, () => {
    // This is the add callback, which is `cb` in the `add.js` file
});
```

*(Frequently, the first two statements above are written as a single statement, e.g. `let add = require("add")(senderFunction);`)*

Basically, the whole thing is one big builder for something that uses a given `send` function, which is injected into it by calling the builder. That way, it can be tested by injecting a testing version of `send`, and used for real by injecting a real version of `send`; and/or various "real" versions of `send` can be used in different environments, transport mechanisms, etc.